# Remove 27 characters from the front of the variable used for random

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
            <div class="links">
            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT url,display FROM `image_url` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($result as $value) {
                    if($value['display'] != 0){
                        echo'<li><a href="?url='.$value['url'].'">'.$value['url'].'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search_btn").click(function(){
            document.forms[0].submit();
        });
        $('.lb-caption').on('click',"button",function(){
            var link = $(this).parents('.lightbox').find('.lb-image').attr("src");
            console.log('sdf');
            var a = $("<a>")
            .attr("href", link)
            .attr("download", link)
            .appendTo("body");
            a[0].click();
            a.remove();
        });
        $('.random_btn').click(function(){
            var length =$('.links').find('a').length;
            var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * length) + 0);
            var link = $('.links').find('a').get(index);
            $("#search").val(link).focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to remove the first 27 characters from the value that is used for #search (link) but can't seem to figure it out.  Anyone?

Comment: `link = link.slice(27);`?

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do…but If the value you are trying to remove character from is just a string, you can use `someString.slice(27)` that will give you everything after the 27th character.

Comment: I added some additional code to hopefully clarify, but basically there is a list of links that I am randomly pulling one from.  The have the full URL on the front, which I don't want, so I am trying to trim the first 27 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to split the href eg: ...url.split('?url=')[1]...or use slice as described in comments - why don't you simply have the desired url listed as a data attribute. Then on clicking the link - get the data-url value and you will have the sdesired content with no messy manipulations.

Note I have just dodgied up some links with data-urls and its not in PHP - but it should give you the idea.

```js
$('#links-list li').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).find('a').attr('data-url');
  console.log(url); //gives the value of the data-url attribute - eg: "test1"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="links-list">
  <li><a href="?url='test1" data-url="test1">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="?url='test2" data-url="test2">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="?url='test3" data-url="test3">Test 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Honestly?  Cause I don't know enough to know how to do that. :)

Comment: Its as simple as ... echo'<li><a href="?url='.$value['url'].'" data-url=" '. $value['url' ] . ' ">'.$value['url'].'</a></li>';